# CSS Border and Animation

Tags: css, animation, border

[image]

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right></div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#left{
border-right:solid 1px black;
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
#right
{
border-top:solid 1px black;
border-top-left-radius:10px;
}
```

this is how my border on the page looks like, but I cant figure how to get rid of that thing on top, the right div has border radius of top left corner set to 10px and the left div has bottom right set to the same ammount. now the problem is the border between them, it's held by the left div and on the top where I don't want it to be seen a little stick remains, how do I get rid of this?

and second: Trying the css3 animation, once it runs all the way(I'm changing the width on hover) it jumps back to original...how can I make it so that the width would change, but only go back once the mouse is off?
the animation code:

```
@keyframes btn
{
0%{width:80%}
1000%{width:100%}
}
@-webkit-keyframes btn
{
0%{width:80%}
100%{width:100%}
}
.button:hover
{
animation:btn 1s;
}
```

Comment: Those are two questions, which should be, ehm, two questions. Both questions have the same issues though. What have you tried? What HTML do you have? What CSS and/or Javascript are you using? Show us!

Comment: updated with the code

Comment: OK... I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/mPbNd/) of it, but it doesn't look like your screenshot at all, even after correcting the error. So can you update the fiddle with your _actual_ content?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mPbNd/1/  
sorry, forgot to add float left :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial solution is to move the left div down by 10 pixels, by giving it a top margin the same size as the border radius.

```
margin-top:10px;
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/mPbNd/3/)

However, if you do that, there's a problem with the rounded corner of the right div: it starts as 1 pixel wide on top, but shrinks to 0 pixels wide to the left, because the left border width is 0.

Solution: give the right div a left border as well. And then move the whole thing 1 pixel to the left, so the borders overlap (otherwise, the borders would be side by side).

```
border-left:solid 1px black;
position:relative; left:-1px;
```

[Even more updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/mPbNd/4/)